# Is it possible to merge csv files that have similar names(column) in python?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have 3 CSV files that i want to merge.
First one having the column header being movies_title, release_date, genre
Second one having show_id, type, title
Third one having title, rating ,ratingLevel.

Is there a way to merge so it will be like title, release_date,genre, show_id, type, rating, ratingLevel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming df1, df2 & df3 are three dataframes loaded in python;

**Solution1:**

First maybe you can rename title column for df1 & then merge all 3 like this;

```
df1.rename(columns={'movies_title':'title'}, inplace=True)

from functools import reduce
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='title'), dfs)
```

**Solution2:**

If you don't wish to rename any of your columns then this shall work;

```
df_final = df1.merge(df2,how="left",left_on="movies_title",right_on="title")
del df_final["movies_title"]
df_final = df_final.merge(df3,how="left",on="title")
```

**Solution3**
Not sure if this is the best way to get similar columns from 2 different data frames, but you can do fuzzy matching of all combination of columns of 2 dfs then do the merging;

```
col1 = ["movies_title", "release_date", "genre"] # df1.columns
col2 = ["show_id", "type", "title"] # df2.columns
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
lst_col,num = [], [] 
for i in col1: 
    for j in col2:
        lst_col.append([i,j])
        num.append(fuzz.ratio(i,j))    
best_match = lst_col[num.index(max(num))]

# Output of best_match:
# ['movies_title', 'title']

df_final = df1.merge(df2,how="left",left_on=best_match[0],right_on=best_match[1])
```

Comment: what if its not this file? like it might not be title. might be name for the first solution

Comment: Yeah, I thought so at the time while posting answer... that's why came up with 2nd solution... If we the column on which data is required to merge is not fixed then probably have to go with solution2... where you can specify column names for both tables...

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent I've added one more solution 3: where even if we don't know the columns on which dfs needed to merge, but those columns might be similar... this solution does the job, but not sure if this is the optimal way... you can implement this maybe... Thanks